# sending files to a remote pc (webservices, create a server, internet com..)?

Tags: android, web-services, file, wifi

i'm working in an **android app** for comunication with a wireless sensors network, i save the data that i receive from the network in a record file, and now, i want to send that file (normally .txt) to a computer, kinda "server", **by WiFi or 3G**.

I already know use sockets communication if the "server" is connected to the same WiFi conexion, but the problem appears if i want maybe to send the file to a pc in other place, connected to other LAN. I've been reading about **WEBSERVICES** but i have some doubts about the communication with web sites, because i don't have one. Maybe, i should create a server online to have some URL where send the record files. (i don't know how to create ir neither :/)

to sum up, i want to send a file from a device (for example with ip 138.100.XX.XX) to another terminal, a pc (for example with ip 192.21.XX.XX)

¿any good tutorial about this? any advice?? what do you think about??

Thank you very much, also for reading :)

Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link may have some help [Android device to PC's socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880059/android-device-to-pcs-socket-connection).

(This talks about basic connection to other PC before sending data/files)

Comment: i've used a similar structure to the communication in the same lan, but can i create a socket with another device just like that, making new Socket (IP,PORT) ??